# Question regarding browser windows when integrating with 3rd party payment software

Tags: web-browser, compliance, hardening, credit-card

I've been told that when integrating with a 3rd party payment gateway, the other website's window should not be opened in an iFrame or a separate window - that the current application window itself should redirect to the payment gateway.

1. Where will I find documentation supporting this claim?
2. A new page would be totally secure. So is there a reason for this rule rule other than to allow the website to continue with the transaction

Comment: Have you asked for the person who told you that for documentation?  Sounds like implementation guidance from the 3rd party.  The rule is probably to allow the 3rd party control over the transaction flow and relatively seamless integration.  These aren't PCI requirements.

Comment: I have and the answer was that these are PCI requirements: I'm trying to validate the claim.

Comment: I heard differently from a consultant (no problem using an IFrame). however, it introduces other, technical hurdles - the main one for me was the default 3rd party cookie blocking from unvisited sites in some firefox versions - which requires your users visit a domain before that domain can write cookies (in an IFrame) - this means after SSO login to your payment gateway (if you do SSO), the browser won't store the session cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**These are not PCI requirements.**

You should read the [PCI DSS E-commerce Guidelines](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/PCI_DSS_v2_eCommerce_Guidelines.pdf).  Section 3.4 describes "Common E-commerce Implementations" such as:

1. 3rd party API with Direct Post
2. iFrame embedding 3rd party payment page in Merchant's site
3. Redirection to 3rd party payment page

and, to quote,

> These examples are intended to be representative of only a few of the
>   most commonly found basic implementations. By no means are they meant
>   to cover the vast range of deployments, hardware components, software
>   applications, and hosting/services models that may exist.

Number 3 is what your contact has told you you *are required to do*.  They are incorrect if they claim that PCI requires you to be limited to that, obviously.  They probably mean that's what *they* support and you should do it and waving around PCI is an effective bully stick.

As a rule of thumb, any business partner that tells you you must do something because of PCI should be able to quote line and verse at you.  List which item of the PCI DSS or SAQ that they feel you're in danger of violating.  That gives you the information you need to resolve the issue.  A business partner who says "PCI says" but can't or won't say where is usually lying or confused.

(Sometimes you have to dig for it; often policies get determined by people who don't deal with customers, but get propagated by support and account management personnel, who don't know what drives the requirements.  But you should always be able to ask for an answer from somewhere up the chain).

Answer (score 2):

Opening a new window or iframe does not change the [protections provided by the Same-Origin Policy](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2).  The [origin inherit ice rules for iframes](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Origin_inheritance_rules) prevents two different domains from accessing each-others data.

There is no security or PCI-DSS requirement that would require a redirect from/to a payment gateway.  This maybe a usability requirement mandated by a specific payment gateway.